# Specify length of bar in a stacked bar chart based on a different column

Tags: google-sheets, plot

I have a table representing the state of a machine per cycle and what percent of time during the cycle was the machine in a particular state. It will look something like this:

```
_________________________________________
| Cycle | State | Percentage_State |
| :---- | :---- | :--------------- |
| 1     | 10    | 60               |
| 1     | 11    | 40               |
| 2     | 27    | 30               |
| 2     | 26    | 70               |
| 3     | 20    | 100              |
| 4     | 23    | 100              |
| 5     | 16    | 85               |
| 5     | 17    | 5                |
| 5     | 18    | 10               |
------------------------------------
```

I would like to represent this data in a chart where the (stacked) bar in cycle = 1 is 60% labelled as state = 10 and 40% stacked on top labelled as 11.

Similarly the bar representing cycle = 5 will be 85% state = 16, 5% state = 17 and 10% state = 18.

The x axis of the chart I am trying to make should be "Cycle". The y axis would just go from 0-100 where the stacked bars of each state will be.

How do I achieve this in google sheets?

I tried using the stacked chart option in google sheets but it is not able to take values of "State" column bar length from the next Percentage column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformat your data to look like this:

| Cycle | %1 | %2 | %3 | state1 | state2 | state3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 | 40 |  | 10 | 11 |  |
| 2 | 30 | 70 |  | 27 | 26 |  |
| 3 | 100 |  |  | 20 |  |  |
| 4 | 100 |  |  | 23 |  |  |
| 5 | 85 | 5 | 10 | 16 | 17 | 18 |

Then select the whole range and create a '100% stacked column chart'. Remove state1/state2/state3 from the list of series, then click the '3 dots' menu on each series and add the state columns as the labels for each (so for series %1 use state1 as labels, etc.)

Comment: A shorter method based off your idea I thought was using state values directly as column names instead of %1, %2 and so on and then using it to create the stacked graph. Works well for me.